# Class missing after repacking jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm trying to work with the Java Simulation library (http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/research/JAVASIMULATION/).
However, when i imported the library, the import name said "default package".
So i repackaged it using jarjar. This seems to work fine if it wasn't for the fact that one class (Coroutine$Runner, see pic) is still in the  folder. [Class missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwVpX.png)
The Coroutine$Runner class is in the same map as all the other classes and showed up with all the other classes originally in the "default package" map, but hasn't been transferred with the rest to the new jar.

Does anyone know how to go about this? How can i get that class included in the new jar?

When i try to include it in the terminal with `jar uf javaSimulationFix.jar Coroutine$Runner.class`
 There appears a copy of Coroutine.class in default package instead of incorporating Coroutine$Runner.class with the rest.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The Coroutine$Runner.class file is in the tgz on the site you list. I don't know why it isn't in your jar, there isn't enough detail on your packaging commands. I will say the tgz file organization is unlike other jars I've seen, but if you can run it without making a jar (i.e., with all .class in separate files in a directory structure), then you should be able to create a jar from that structure.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! 
I made a new jar with the source files and all is well now.
Still it's strange that it originally remained in the default package.
I'm thinking that in the original build there must have been something wrong with the initiation of the Runner class inside the Coroutine class.
(I'll admit i haven't seen a class inside another class before this).

Comment: Normally those "$" classes are generated at *compile* time, not runtime, so it's hard to see what could have "been wrong" with the file to cause the problem. I think it more likely that, due to the unusual structure of the tgz and/or the 'default package' location, that it just got left out of the jar you wanted to make somehow.